# .bowerrc is where will be located in project directory?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, bower

I'm looking through the angular tutorial it mention the .bowerrc file. But for me, the .bowerrc file is missing. I couldn't find the file in myapp.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it then add it manually. You can find the docs here with some .bowerrc examples.

[Bower documentation](https://bower.io/docs/config/)

Basic example:

```
{
    "directory": "app/components/",
    "timeout": 120000,
    "registry": {
        "search": [
            "http://localhost:8000",
            "https://bower.herokuapp.com"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this step but  next  when i tried to install the angular-route its again create  the folder  bower components.

Comment: @ShanmugamM The folder bower_components include all the libraries that you have installed using bower, so it's correct. What's your problem then?

Comment: I couldn't found .bowerrc file

Comment: I couldn't find the .bowerrc file so that i tried to create the .bowerrc i am beginner in Angular

Comment: Since it's a file that starts with a '.' maybe it's there but it's hidden.